# .Net page with VS 2008 report in Report Viewer fails to redirect to sub report content

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, html, subreport

A .Net web page hosting a VS 2008 report in a report viewer control fails to redirect to any sub report links, instead the page refreshes to display the main report content. This report is a dash board report that generated and rendered data for the current day (and back) and hence does not require any parameters. Similar report with sub report links does work in the same project. Any ideas?

Comment: As it turns out, the report content was being loaded and rendered in the Page Load as it did not require any param data input. However. once the report rendering was forced through a post back on a button submit, the report started to function as it was intended to. I am not sure if having this page in an update panel of a master page had anything to do with it too but there is some documentation regarding the partial rendering of content from report viewer control. Please feel free to add more detail to the specifics for the root cause of the problem.